# Developing sharepoint solution in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

I want to develop sharepoint solution in visual studio 2008..i have installed visual studio 2008 extensions for sharepoint from microsoft site.

I am in search of free videos or tutorials that explains me step by step development of sharepoint solution using visual studio 2008 (using installed sharepoint templates)

Any good links?

Answer (score -1):

Kushal,

there's a range of videos and web casts available on the Office Developer Center (MSDN).

[Videos and Web casts for SharePoint server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa940989.aspx):

[How do I videos for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/office/ee534018.aspx):

This should help you along a bit - once you got the fundamentals down then you need to narrow your criteria for each topic (easier to find information that way).

Another good source of SharePoint information is [SharePointDevWiki](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com) - doesn't have videos but a lot of useful information about both How-To, Tools and approaches to different scenarios.